# audio waveform to Integer sequence

Tags: c++, audio, waveform

I need to create an Integer Sequence from an Audio file. I was checking the waveform libraries as that draw a linear graph. But I am searching for the key information, What is the source of the integer that is used to draw the graph ? is it amplitude ? frequency ? or something else ?  There are libraries available but I need to know what unit of information I need to extract to have a data that I can feed to a graph. However drawing a graph is not my objective. I just want that raw integer array.

Comment: Depends on the type of audio file you're talking about. `.wav` is pretty simple (amplitudes at fixed intervals). Compressed formats are more complex, but most use some sort of transform (DCT, FFT, etc.) to convert from individual samples to frequency-based encoding.

Comment: any type will work, I just need to know the process. I am okay with wav

Comment: In that case, you'll need to deal with the [Wave File Format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's the amplitudes what you need to get a wave oscillogram, and it's the way PCM data are stored in wav files, for example (data which come directly after the file header). Note that there are 8-bit and 16-bit formats, the latter may be also big-endian or little-endian depending on the byte order (just to keep you aware of it).

Comment: Then Whats the role of frequency in music ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: Roughly speaking, a quickly changing 'local amplitude' produces a signal containing various frequencies, which can be represented as Fourier series. As for the music, 440 Hz is the standard frequency of a tuning fork.  In computing, a waveform is just a set of discrete samples.

Answer (score 0):

Audio is simply a curve - when you plot it with time across the X axis then Y axis is amplitude - similar to plotting a sin math function - each point on the curve is a number which gets stored in the audio file - WAV format this number typically is a 16 bit unsigned integer - so ignoring the 44 byte header - the rest of the file is just a sequence of these integer numbers.  When this curve varies up and down quickly over time the frequency is higher than if the curve varies more slowly over time.  If you download the audio workbench application :  Audacity you can view this curve of any audio file (WAV, mp3,...)

Comment: and what is the role of frequency in music ? if its all with amplitude

Comment: if you draw on a sheet of paper one cycle of a sin curve - across its 360 degrees using up the entire sheet of paper from left to right - lets consider it a low frequency relative to when you draw 10 such cycles across the paper - amplitude is the height of the curve and frequency is just a count of the number of high and low amplitude points per unit of time - the number of cycles per second - lookup Hertz

Comment: being able to see audio curves may help - install the application :   Audacity  and open up various WAV,mp3 audio files - it lets you hear while it shows you the audio curve

Comment: The short answer is - the only variable you have control over is amplitude, and how quickly you vary amplitude determines frequency - see this for details :  http://www.billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/LectureNotes/AudioData.html